# Get data source row number of Pivot Table Active Cell

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I need to find a way of determining the row number from the data source table of the selected cell in my pivot table.

The reasoning behind this is that I want to be able to edit/update the values from a UserForm.

My table with the data source is in sheet 1 named Data and my pivot table is in sheet 2, named Project management.

I know I can edit values in a Pivot Table by setting

```
EnableDataValueEditing = False
```

..but this does not give me the desired result since my original data remains unchanged and I also have hidden columns that I use for conditional formatting only and it would be a bad user experience to have to unhide the columns every time I need to edit them.

Does anyone have any idea or suggestion as to how I can retrieve the original data row number for a specific cell in my pivot table ?

[As an example, the top is my original table and the bottom right is my pivot table. When the cell "Dummy Data" is pressed, I want it to give me the Row number of that data from my original table.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0PQ9.png)

> A "bad" workaround would be to use VBA to match the selected cell
> value with the data from the table and when the match is found,
> retrieve the address but this is not foolproof, the data should be
> unique but with more data flowing in over time, this might not be the
> case anymore. Therefore I am trying to avoid this method.

> PS: if someone could edit my post and embed the image, I would highly
> appreciate it.

Comment: I'm confused. Shouldn't the source be many rows? A sum of rows? Have you tried double clicking on the data in the pivot table? That level of preview doesn't help?

Comment: @Brett , thank you for the comment. Well, it does not for my desired end result. I am adding new rows of data to my original table through a user form and then I am refreshing my pivot table to show that data, therefore i would like to also be able to edit the existing data from it. By clicking on a cell in my pivot table and retrieving the row number of that data from my original table, it would help me to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

A pivot table is a report summarizing information from the linked table or query. The only ways you're going to be able to update the information is if you know the row ID/number you want to change or filter the data source down to a point where you can identify it.

If you're going to be keeping and altering records, I'd suggest building a database (Access, for something quick and easy) to enforce some form of integrity and then link your pivot table and form to that database.

EDIT: VLookup or Index(Match(...)) is only going to return the first hit and that may not necessarily be what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I will put my non-orthodox but perfectly functional way of doing it just in case someone is facing a similar issue or until a better way arises.

I have actually added a new column in my data table with the formula

```
=ROW([@Column1])
```

This gives me the row number for every entry.

Next I am just adding that column as a row in my pivot table, display in tabular mode to have it's own column and hide it. Therefore when selecting a cell, I am looking in the hidden column for the number and therefore I am getting the source data row number.